# Dynamically generated datepicker with default running date values

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm trying to generate multiple jquery datepicker input field dynamically, and put a default running date on each input field.
So, I will have 10 input fields, the first datepicker input will show today's date, ex: 2016-03-22, the second will show 2016-03-23, third will show 2016-03-24, etc.

here is my code

```
function addDays(theDate, days) {
  return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var days = addDays(new Date(), j);
    console.log(days);
    $("#date-picker"+j).datepicker({"setDate": days,
    format:'yyyy-dd-mm',    
    autoclose:true
    });
}
```

when I check on the console, I got the correct date, however it's not showing in each input field, I'm not sure what did I do wrong.

when I do as below it works, but the rest of the attribute like format and autoclose won't be available.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var days = addDays(new Date(), j);
    $("#date-picker"+j).datepicker("setDate", days);
}
```

pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to parse date format first because `Date()` constructor is not supported cross-browserly yet

```
function addDays(theDate, days) {
  return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  var days = addDays(new Date(), j);
  console.log(days);
  $("#date-picker" + j).datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-dd-mm",
    autoclose:true
  });
  $('#date-picker'+j).datepicker("setDate", days);
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdMLqZ?editors=1010)**

Comment: I added onSelect attribute, but it doesn't seems to work?